# Does a PHP post request to the current server private IP go through the load balancer if the server is behind one?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, load-balancing

I have a function within wordpress that is used to send POST requests to specific web servers, referred to as `ALLOWED_SERVERS`, which are all located within a private IP range. These `ALLOWED_SERVERS` are all behind a load balancer. However, I've face an issue where, I start update a post on https://dev.com and the request does not set correctly.

```php
define(
    'ALLOWED_SERVERS',
    [
        '192.168.0.1',
        '192.168.0.2',
    ]
);

function create_purge_request_data($server_ip): array
{
    $url = parse_url(home_url());

    return [
        'url' => "{$url['scheme']}://{$server_ip}/wp-json/cache/v1/purge/",
        'type' => 'POST',
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Host' => $url['host']
        ],
        'data' => json_encode(['host' => $url['host']])
    ];
}

function send_purge_cache_request()
{
    $request_data = array_map('create_purge_request_data', ALLOWED_SERVERS);
    Requests::request_multiple($request_data);
}

add_action('post_updated', 'send_purge_cache_request');
```

- I have checked the nginx log on the first server (192.168.0.1), but noticed that the access ip has been changed to the public IP of the same server. Ideally, it should remain as 192.168.0.1, since the requests are being sent to and from the same server. Additionally, the request URL has been modified to "https://testdev.com//wp-json/cache/v1/purge/". (I accessed the first server using the command 'ssh testdev.com').

```
0.245 101.108.225.123 - - [02/Aug/2023:17:48:50 +0900] "POST //wp-json/cache/v1/purge/ HTTP/1.1" 404 164 "https://testdev.com//wp-json/cache/v1/purge/" "php-requests/1.7-3470169" "-" "-" "testdev.com"
```

- I have also checked the nginx log on the second server (192.168.0.2), but I noticed that the access IP and the URL differ from those on the first server. I expected that the host result would be dev.com, from which I sent a request, not testdev.com.

```
0.000   192.168.0.1     -       [01/Aug/2023:14:20:48 +0900]    "POST /wp-json/cache/v1/purge/ HTTP/1.1"        301     162     "http://192.168.0.2/wp-json/cache/v1/purge/"    "php-requests/1.7-3470169"      "-"
     "-"     "testdev.com"     "-"
```

The question is, why does the request shown in the nginx log indicate that it was sent from testdev.com, instead of the actual source, dev.com, as per the above code?

Comment: I’m not clear on your question. Is something not working, or is it just unexpected in the logs?

Comment: For https requests to function correctly, the [server name indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) configuration must match the hostname presented in the request. https servers function strangely if at all when you feed them pure IPv4 addresses rather than hostnames. That's because the certificate validation is tied to the hostname rather than the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

> why does the request shown in the nginx log indicate that it was sent from testdev.com, instead of the actual source, dev.com, as per the above code?

It doesn't.

Your log entry does not conform to the standard formats. I suspect that what is being reported here is the virtual host which handled the request.

Since you are using the IP address for the HTTP request, this is bypassing the load balancer and going directly the the webserver. It *appears* that the wordpress installation you are targetting with the request is running on a virtual host OTHER than the default.

As to how you *should* be doing this....that's a more complicated question.

Generally hard-coded IP addresses are bad. And where your sites sit behind a load balancer then such an approach will not scale beyond a single site. OTOH you've not provided any details about the load balancer nor nginx.

If it were me, I would create specific aliases for each node in the nginx config and on the load balancer, e.g. if your site is 'www.example.com', I would set `server_name www.example.com www*.example.com;` in the nginx config and either on the load balancer map:

```
www.example.com: 192.168.0.1
www.example.com: 192.168.0.2
www-1.example.com: 192.168.0.1
www-2.example.com: 192.168.0.2
```

...or add the specific records in DNS pointing directly at the origin hosts.

and use the sepecific alias in $ALLOWED_SERVERS.

....and since you probably need an access control mechanism to prevent abuse, you will probably be limiting the access to /wp-json/cache/v1/purge - but without knowing what that looks like, I can't advise.